# How can I change the default download location to the external SD Card?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, sd-card, files, download-manager

I have a Chinese tablet that runs Android 4.4.2 (KitKat) and comes with the default Download Manager. I googled for a way to change the default download location to the external SD card with no luck. Can anyone advise me how to do this? I don't have the my files app as stated in most solutions.

[image: Screenshot of Download Manager]
[image: Second screenshot of Download Manager]

<sub>Click image(s) for larger version</sub>

Comment: 1. Did you solve this? 2. Pls post an example of the solutions you tried that didn't work 3. I have 'My Files' 1.0 pre-installed by Samsung, but I don't see any option in that to change default download folder.

Comment: Hello, I couldn't find a solution from the default app however I thin my files has the option somewhere. I found multiple apps on Playstore that does have this option.